# storing complex perl data structures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, perl, persistence

I work on a large perl website that currently stores all the configurations in a perl module. I have the need to move these settings into MySQL. The problem is the settings are defined in lots of variables and most of them are complex structures (like hash of hashes and array of hashes).

My first idea was to use either XML, YAML, or Storable perl module to easily write and read the variables from a simple file, but my boss doesn't want either of these solutions. He wants it to be stored in MySQL, so other solutions are not an option.

My question is,  does anybody know about any CPAN module(s) that will help me to do that task; what I basically need is a way to map all the perl complex perl structures I have to MySQL tables.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:** Store the data in serialized form (Data::Dumper, Storable, JSON, etc...) in MySQL's TEXT/MEDIUMTEXT/LONGTEXT type field (65KB/16MB/4GB max sizes respectively)

**Option 2:** Use DBIx ORM (Object-to-Relational-Mapping), which is the way to automatically map Perl data to DB tables (similar to Java's Hybernate). You'll need to convert your data structures to objects as far as I'm aware, though there may be DBIx module that can deal with non-blessed data structures.

Frankly, unless you need to manipulate the config data in detail within MySQL piece by piece, option #1 is dramatically simpler. However, if your boss's goal is to be able to either query details of configuration, or manipulate its individual elements one by one, you will have to go with #2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will certainly explore the DBIx path (although I think using this seems overkill for what I need, but I haven't found any simpler/easier solution yet, so that's the best solution so far)

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to `use Storable qw(freeze thaw)` with MySQL?

Comment: because my boss wants the settings to be easily editable using just MySQL commands (as a matter of fact I've tried that approach but my boss rejected it because he can't edit them directly)